# docker bind mount volume named like "ts_00:00:00", i.e. with a column in name

Tags: docker

I realized that I am unable to execute bind mount with a volume that has a column in name, e.g.

```sh
docker run -v /mnt/fs/ts_00\:00\:00:/mnt/data container_name bash
```

fails with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/mnt/fs/ts_00:00:00:/mnt/data'.
```

I wonder if it is possible to get a volume with columns in the name to bind mount inside a docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `--mount` instead of `-v` because colon is a the divider of source/target in the `-v` argument ([source](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604#issuecomment-332673783))

Was not sure if `ts_00:00:00` is a file or a directory

I ran this and this works

```
mkdir "ts_00:00:00"
docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/ts_00:00:00/,destination=/tmp/hi -it bash
```

tried to prepare the command for you based on what you provided, but not sure if it's correct

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/fs/ts_00:00:00,destination=/mnt/data -it container_name bash
```

see more [in the GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604)